# SOAP post() operation gets Java nullptr exception

Tags: ruby, soap, savon, zeep

I'm having an issue with Ruby code posting SOAP using Savon

I have a parameter XML_BODY which apparently is not being sent, or, if it is, looks null to the Java code receiving it (if I try to return "TEST"+XML_BODY, the response shows "TEST null")

The other data seems to be sending okay - really confused

Client operations are pub_mugs(), post(), subscribe()

This Python/Zeep code **succeeds completely**

```
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

if __name__ == "__main__":

  url="http://localhost:8080/Wormhole?wsdl"

  with open('../../web/web/xsd/DETEP2012-with-content.xml', 'r') as f:
    xml=f.read().replace('\n', '')

  session = Session()
  session.verify = False
  transport = Transport(session=session)
  client = Client(url, transport=transport)

  print client.service.PubMugs(username='usr',password='pwd') #SUCCESS

  print client.service.subscribe(username='usr',password='pwd') #SUCCESS

  print client.service.post(username='usr',password='pwd',mug='110',XML_BODY=xml) #SUCCESS
```

This Ruby/Savon code succeeds for the pub_mugs() and subscribe(), but **fails for post()**

```
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: ENV["WSDL"],
      :ssl_verify_mode => :none,
      :raise_errors => false,
      pretty_print_xml: true)

  doc = File.open("../web/web/xsd/DETEP2012-with-content.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

  xml = doc.to_xml.delete("\n").split(">",2)[1] # Removes initial <?xml ... >

  ap xml # The XML here looks correct

  response_pub_mugs = client.call(:pub_mugs, message: { username: "usr", password: "pwd" } )

  ap response_pub_mugs #SUCCESS

  response_subscribe = client.call(:subscribe, message: { username: "usr", password: "pwd" } )      

  ap response_subscribe #SUCCESS

  #THIS CALL FAILS!
  response_post = client.call(:post,
    message: {
      username: "usr",
      password: "pwd",
      mug: "110",
      XML_BODY: xml
    }
  )
```

FAULT RESPONSE IS THIS

```
:fault => {
     :faultcode => "S:Server",
     :faultstring => "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    :"@xmlns:ns4" => "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
}
```

The stack trace doesn't tell me much

```
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at seti.Wormhole.post(Wormhole.java:103)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
```

The WSDL file

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://seti/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://seti/" name="Wormhole">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://seti/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/Wormhole?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="PubMugs">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PubMugs"/>
</message>
<message name="PubMugsResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:PubMugsResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="post">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:post"/>
</message>
<message name="postResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:postResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="subscribe">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:subscribe"/>
</message>
<message name="subscribeResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:subscribeResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="Wormhole">
<operation name="PubMugs">
<input wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/PubMugsRequest" message="tns:PubMugs"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/PubMugsResponse" message="tns:PubMugsResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="post">
<input wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/postRequest" message="tns:post"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/postResponse" message="tns:postResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="subscribe">
<input wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/subscribeRequest" message="tns:subscribe"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://seti/Wormhole/subscribeResponse" message="tns:subscribeResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="WormholePortBinding" type="tns:Wormhole">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="PubMugs">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="post">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="subscribe">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="Wormhole">
<port name="WormholePort" binding="tns:WormholePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Wormhole"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

The post() operation runs some Java code that accesses a MySQL database

Maybe Savon is generating a different header? I'm really at a loss - any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT - MORE INFO**

The Java prototype for post()

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "post")
public String post(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password, @WebParam(name = "mug") String mug, @WebParam(name = "XML_BODY") String XML_BODY)
```

BTW I also tried reading the file directly into string xml, skipping the Nokogiri doc

And I've tried removing all whitespace from the string xml, and removed pretty_print

If I change the username or password, I can get this response generated by the Java code, so apparently the Java is happy until this point, and it is accessing the database alright

```
:post_response => {
          :return => "Unknown username or password. Message NOT submitted.",
    :"@xmlns:ns2" => "http://seti/"
}
```

Comment: Just a couple of wild guesses: `pretty_print_xml: true` could you try to set it to `false`, also maybe try with `mug: 110` (integer rather than string, I am not sure whether python coerces it.)

Comment: Good ideas - unfortunately didn't fix it (BTW I also tried reading the file into xml as a string, skipping the Nokogiri doc)

Comment: The prototype for the post(): @WebMethod(operationName = "post")
    public String post(@WebParam(name = "username") String username, @WebParam(name = "password") String password, @WebParam(name = "mug") String mug, @WebParam(name = "XML_BODY") String XML_BODY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

THE ANSWER WAS THIS

Added :none for convert_request_keys_to

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: ENV["WSDL"],
      :ssl_verify_mode => :none,
      :raise_errors => false,
      pretty_print_xml: false,
      convert_request_keys_to: :none)
```

Used literal strings for hash keys

```
response_post = client.call(:post, message: { 'username': 'usr', 'password': 'pwd', 'mug': '110', 'XML_BODY': xml })
```